# How to order result dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, iqueryable

I am trying to apply sorting dynamically. I am using `EntityFramework`. I am passing `sortorder` and `sortfield`. Now I don't want to write conditions to order result by `sortfield` column. What I have tried is as below,

```
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByProperty<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string property, string sortorder)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "t");
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, property);
        var ex = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TKey>>(member, param);
        return source.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(ex);
    }
```

And I call it as below,

```
OrderByProperty<Class, dynamic>(objClass, sortfield, sortorder);
```

I am getting below error when `sortfield` is of type `System.Int32`;

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

same for `string`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You **might** need to [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.convert?view=netframework-4.8) the `member` first to `TKey`, before using it in the Expression.Lambda. Like: `Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TKey>>(Expression.Convert(member, typeof(TKey)), param);`

Comment: The name of the property you are passing in (`string property`) needs to be the same type as the second type parameter in the method call (`TKey`). That's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this extension method:

```
  public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
  {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
   }
```